# What is the convention for returning a side-effect in Scheme?

Tags: lisp, scheme, sicp

I'm going through the *Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs* MIT video lecture series, and I had a quick question about returning side-effects from functions.

In [video 3A](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-001-structure-and-interpretation-of-computer-programs-spring-2005/video-lectures/3a-henderson-escher-example/), the professor writes a quick equation for `for-each` similar to this:

```
(define (for-each p l)
   (if (null? l)
      "done"
      (p (car l)
         (for-each p (cdr l)))))
```

Is there a specific convention for returning a side-effect from a function in Scheme, or was the `"done"` an arbitrary choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not really a *side effect*, but rather that every Scheme function must return something. The string `"done"` is something. Normally, when you call `for-each` you might do something like:

```
(for-each (lambda (x) (display x)) lst)
```

and ignore the return value from `for-each`. The author could have just as easily chosen any other value to return from the base case.

Comment: +1. Note that the [standard (R6RS) `for-each`](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_idx_644) returns an unspecified value. In SCM, it's in fact a value displayed as `#<unspecified>`.

Comment: I mean, is there a value that symbolizes "nothing" in Scheme... besides the empty list?

Comment: @larsmans: So do you return `#<unspecified>` by not returning anything from the function or is it an explicit value...

Comment: @JoshVoigts: It's not possible to "not return anything from a function" because the body of a function is an expression and every expression in the language must evaluate to a value. `#<unspecified>` is some custom value that a particular implementation of Scheme arbitrarily decided is the result of a function which the standard leaves up to the implementation to decide what to return.

Comment: A standard, simple way of getting this "unspecified" value is `(if #f #t)`. So your example of a for-each program could have switched the true and false branches and then deleted the false branch to return this "unspecified" value.